# zsh clears previous line of prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt, prezto, zsh-zle, fzf

I have a multi-line prompt in zsh. I've found that sometimes when I `CTRL-C` out of an autocompletion the previous line of the prompt gets erased unexpectedly. Here's a gif showing this happening with `ls`, `vim` and `fzf`: [http://imgur.com/1jTrrzA](https://imgur.com/1jTrrzA)

Here's an outline of events that happen:

1. `ls` all the files
2. `ls` then tab complete and `CTRL-C` out of the first completion (previous line of prompt gets erased)
3. `ls` then tab complete and `CTRL-C` out of the second completion. The previous line of the prompt doesn't get erased
4. same as step 2 but with `vim` instead
5. same as step 3 but I hit `Enter` instead of `CTRL-C`, this is my mistake. However, if I `CTRL-C` out of this example (the not-first completion) the previous line isn't erased
6. Show how `fzf` suffers from the same problem several times

I've found that the issue as shown during step 2 and step 4 still exists with a single line prompt. However `fzf` isn't broken with a single line prompt.

My entire prompt can be found at http://pastebin.com/JwufRy6m which is a modified version of https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_sorin_setup to work with mercurial repositories at my company. The lines of interest (I think) in my prompt file are 166 and 167 (line 167 == line 166 minus `$prompt_newline`).

I've tried creating a multiline prompt without using `$prompt_newline` by doing:

```
NEWLINE=$'\n'
PROMPT=.....${NEWLINE}....
```

But that didn't help either which kinda makes sense to me because part of the problem still exists with single-line prompts.

Comment: Please post the contents of `PS1` *here*, rather than a link to the script that generates it.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug in Prezto. Prezto has a new community fork. Please open an issue there: https://github.com/zsh-users/prezto/issues